What do these それs refer to here?
From Kokoro chapter 7,

私は不思議に思った。しかし私は先生を研究する気でその宅へ出入りをするのではなかった。私はただそのままにして打ち過ぎた。今考えるとその時の私の態度は、私の生活のうちでむしろ尊むべきものの一つであった。私は全くそのために先生と人間らしい温かい交際ができたのだと思う。もし私の好奇心が幾分でも先生の心に向かって、研究的に働き掛けたなら、二人の間を繋ぐ同情の糸は、何の容赦もなくその時ふつりと切れてしまったろう。若い私は全く自分の態度を自覚していなかった。それだから尊いのかも知れないが、もし間違えて裏へ出たとしたら、どんな結果が二人の仲に落ちて来たろう。私は想像してもぞっとする。先生はそれでなくても、冷たい眼で研究されるのを絶えず恐れていたのである。

I am bit uncertain what these それs refer to. I think the first それ refers to 自分の態度 (maybe 若い私は全く自分の態度を自覚していなかった?). I am not sure about the second one. I guess 先生はそれでなくても means "even if Sensei is not that kind of person who does not accept the fact that I was not aware of my attitude"?

「それでなくても」（≈「ただでさえ」） is a fixed expression, no?

Oh thanks, I didn't notice that.

I can't be 100% sure, but I think the first それ refers to "私は全く自分の態度を自覚していなかった". I.e. the innocence of the author who not only wasn't trying to find out about the Sensei, but who also wasn't even aware of how they approached Sensei in a way that did not involve trying to find out about Sensei.
The second それでなくても means "regardless" and you can roughly think of それ to be referring to the topic being discussed (so it means, even in the absence of the situation we are discussing here, Sensei was in general weary of 冷たい眼で研究される).
